# How to instantiate my Interface object inside Junit test class?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit5

I am getting NullPointerException at this line:  `Role additionalRole = this.roleService.getRoleByAuthority(userRegistrationModel.getAdditionalRole());` Because roleService object is not initialised..This is an interface object How can I instantiate inside Junit class? I have tried initializing using constructor Then I see error called "Test class should have exactly one public zero argument constructor so I cant initialize it with my constructor as well..Below is my full code. Can someone suggest here?

```
package com.doctorAppointmentBookingSystem.serviceImpl;
    
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    
    import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;


import com.doctorAppointmentBookingSystem.entity.Doctor;
    import com.doctorAppointmentBookingSystem.entity.Role;
    import com.doctorAppointmentBookingSystem.entity.User;
    import com.doctorAppointmentBookingSystem.entity.WeekSchedule;
    import com.doctorAppointmentBookingSystem.model.bindingModel.DoctorRegistrationModel;
    import com.doctorAppointmentBookingSystem.model.bindingModel.UserRegistrationModel;
    import com.doctorAppointmentBookingSystem.repository.DoctorRepository;
    import com.doctorAppointmentBookingSystem.repository.UserRepository;
    import com.doctorAppointmentBookingSystem.service.RoleService;

import com.doctorAppointmentBookingSystem.service.UserService;
    import com.doctorAppointmentBookingSystem.service.WeekScheduleService;
@SpringBootTest
    public class DoctorServiceImplTest {

         private ModelMapper modelMapper;
        
           private UserService userService;
        
            private DoctorRepository doctorRepository;

            private WeekScheduleService weekScheduleService;
            private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
           @Autowired
            private RoleService roleService;
            @Autowired
            private UserRepository userRepository;

/*          public DoctorServiceImplTest(RoleService roleService) {
            
                this.roleService = roleService;
            }
        public DoctorServiceImplTest() {
                super();
            }*/
        @Test
        public void saveDoctor() throws ParseException
        {

            DateFormat d2= new SimpleDateFormat("1997-06-25");
            DateFormat d3= new SimpleDateFormat("2010-06-25");
            modelMapper=new ModelMapper();
            bCryptPasswordEncoder= new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
          
            Date d4 = d2.parse("1997-06-25");
            Date d5 = d3.parse("2010-06-25");
            DoctorRegistrationModel d= new DoctorRegistrationModel("sai@gmail.com"
                    ,"ajfjdhskjfh","1234567890","1234567890","shfgjdsgh","shfgjdsgh",
                    "1234567890",d4,"MALE", d5);
            System.out.println(d);
        
            UserRegistrationModel userRegistrationModel = this.modelMapper.map(d, UserRegistrationModel.class);
            
            
            String DEFAULT_DOCTOR_ROLE = "ROLE_DOCTOR";
            System.out.println("userRegistrationModel"+userRegistrationModel);
            userRegistrationModel.setAdditionalRole(DEFAULT_DOCTOR_ROLE);
            
            User user = this.modelMapper.map(userRegistrationModel, User.class);
            String encryptedPassword = this.bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(userRegistrationModel.getPassword());
            user.setPassword(encryptedPassword);
            System.out.println(user);
            user.setAccountNonExpired(true);
            user.setAccountNonLocked(true);
            user.setCredentialsNonExpired(true);
            user.setEnabled(true);
       //     user.addRole(this.roleService.getDefaultRole());
            System.out.println("roleService.."+ roleService);
            
    
            if (userRegistrationModel.getAdditionalRole() != null) {
                Role additionalRole = this.roleService.getRoleByAuthority(userRegistrationModel.getAdditionalRole());
                user.addRole(additionalRole);
                System.out.println("additionalRole.."+ additionalRole);
            }
          User u=  this.userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
             WeekSchedule weekSchedule = this.weekScheduleService.createDefault();
    
                Doctor doctor = this.modelMapper.map(u, Doctor.class);
                doctor.setUser(u);
                doctor.setWeekSchedule(weekSchedule);
                doctorRepository.saveAndFlush(doctor);
        }








        
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! could you please provide an actual exception? It seems like @SpringBootTest annotation doesn't find the Service and it doesn't get initialized for some reason... Also please specify a spring boot version, Maybe you should also add `@ExtendsWith(SpringExtension.class)` before the test

Comment: My spring version is 4.3.7   . Actual exception is Java.lang.NullPointerException at this line:Role additionalRole = this.roleService.getRoleByAuthority(userRegistrationModel.getAdditionalRole());...I tried adding @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) , for somereason there are no suggestions to use SpringExtension.class, it says class<SpringExtension> cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: ... and what is your spring boot version? There might be a "clash" of versions? In general spring boot 2 is supposed to work with spring 5 at least

Comment: I could see 1.5.2 under spring boot starter parent in pom.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of comments, I believe the spring boot / spring versions you're using are too old. If I remember correctly, at that time, spring boot tests used to support junit 4 only, while you're trying to use JUnit 5.
So you have the following options:

1. Downgrade to JUnit 4 and use `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`
2. Upgrade spring / spring boot
3. Try to blend them together with [this article](http://antkorwin.com/junit5/junit5_in_spring4.html). You might also want to read [this article](http://mvpjava.com/spring-boot-junit5/).

Needless to say that solution (2) is the best one :)